# Synchronous calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I want to delete the file after i downloaded it from the server, but the delete method in service executes first even if i place it below the line of download file this is my code:

```
generateClearanceExcel(): void {
    if (this.selectedIds.length > 0) {
        var departureDate = prompt("Please enter departure date.", "");
        if (departureDate !== null && departureDate !== "") {
            this.generating = true;
            this.clearanceService.generateClearanceExcel(this.selectedIds, departureDate).subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.generating = false;
                    window.location.href = "clearance/downloadreport/?fileName=" + result.fileName;
                    this.clearanceService.deleteFile(result.fileName).subscribe();

                    if (result.success == true) {
                        if (result.infos.length > 0) {
                            this.alertService.info(result.infos);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        this.alertService.error(result.errors);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

TIA.

Comment: What does this.clearanceService.generateClearanceExcel do?

Comment: @Deepak it creates an excel file in the folder in the server and returns a json with the filename of the created file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try with timeout

```
generateClearanceExcel(): void {
    if (this.selectedIds.length > 0) {
        var departureDate = prompt("Please enter departure date.", "");
        if (departureDate !== null && departureDate !== "") {
            this.generating = true;
            this.clearanceService.generateClearanceExcel(this.selectedIds, departureDate).subscribe(
                result => {
                    this.generating = false;
                    window.location.href = "clearance/downloadreport/?fileName=" + result.fileName;
                     setTimeout(() => {
                      this.clearanceService.deleteFile(result.fileName).subscribe();
                    }, 3000);
                    setTimeout(function(){  }, 3000);                       

                    if (result.success == true) {
                        if (result.infos.length > 0) {
                            this.alertService.info(result.infos);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        this.alertService.error(result.errors);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: placing the `this.clearanceService.deleteFile(result.fileName).subscribe();` inside the `function(){ }` gives me an error `EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'deleteFile' of undefined`

Comment: You welcome..Previously it didnt work because your are using ES5 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the delete method inside the condition of success of download.

```
    generateClearanceExcel(): void {
        if (this.selectedIds.length > 0) {
            var departureDate = prompt("Please enter departure date.", "");
            if (departureDate !== null && departureDate !== "") {
                this.generating = true;
                this.clearanceService.generateClearanceExcel(this.selectedIds, departureDate).subscribe(
                    result => {
                        this.generating = false;
                        window.location.href = "clearance/downloadreport/?fileName=" + result.fileName;                   

                        if (result.success == true) {
                        this.clearanceService.deleteFile(result.fileName).subscribe();
                        if (result.infos.length > 0) {
                            this.alertService.info(result.infos);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        this.alertService.error(result.errors);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error. it says that the file could not be found, it is because it deletes the file first before download.

Comment: this line `window.location.href = "clearance/downloadreport/?fileName=" + result.fileName;` @sainu

Comment: that means only after downloading we place the code : 
 `this.clearanceService.deleteFile(result.fileName).subscribe();`